# Map superclass and subclass to different tables in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to map a class to a table and a subclass to another table. I'm not sure if you can do this in a proper way. I tried this so far:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "MyTable1")
public class MyClass

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "MyTable2")
public class MySubclass extends MyClass
```

It works but in the generated SQL both tables are joined and I want to keep them seperated.

Another approach was to use the same as above but change JOINED to TABLE_PER_CLASS. This does not work because there is a UNION ALL on both tables in the SQL when I query *MyClass*.

I also tried to use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(polymorphism = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)` and `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(polymorphism = PolymorphismType.IMPLICIT)` but with no effect.

So my question is if there is a way to map this in Hibernate. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

---

Using Hibernate 3.6.1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144172/quering-jpa-table-per-class-mapping-on-one-to-one-relationship for how to avoid the `UNION`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to consider the two entities as completely unrelated, except for the fields they have in common. It's not really an inheritance relationship since when you search for a MyClass, you don't want MySubclass instances to be found, although MySubClass instances are instances of MyClass in your design.

The best solution is thus probably to use a [`MappedSuperclass`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168) (see chapter 2.2.4.4) which contains the common fields and methods, and to create two completely separate entities which extend this mapped super class.

Comment: You are right. And the `MappedSuperclass` solution actually works. Anyhow it seems a little bit inelegant to me because I can't use a `MappedSuperclass` as a `@Entity`. But maybe this is the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE_PER_CLASS` should do what you want.

Note that when you execute a query like `from MyClass m`, Hibernate loads all objects of class `MyClass`, including subclasses, hence the `UNION ALL` clause. If you need only `MyClass` without subclasses, you need to use the following query: `from MyClass m where m.class = MyClass`.

Comment: Note that this won't help with Session.load() and Session.get() calls, which will continue doing the UNION, as well as the navigation through relationships from other entities to MyClass.